# Proposing Windows as its own Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

Is there a reason why we have a "Unix and Linux" Stack Exchange and an "Apple" Stack Exchange but no "Windows" Stack Exchange? (Hell even Ubuntu got its own)

I couldn't find it anywhere so I'm asking.

Since Windows has many users it would be a potent Stack Exchange.

Comment: Area51 proposals: [Microsoft](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10161/microsoft?referrer=dFAVP45dVh7FiYPWF7h04g2) & [Windows Phone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone?referrer=BtnLkTODRmUgCqb_Ka-8vA2)

Comment: @YannisRizos You may want to convert that to an answer.

Comment: @N.N. Feel free to steal my comment, I'm at work, no time... :(

Comment: I just realized that this proposal is not for windows user and their application problems. the article send me to Super User. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @YannisRizos Ok, I posted an answer. I copied your links so that you are still the referrer to the Area51 proposals.

Comment: Just as an aside: I never liked the existence of [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/); I think questions that are a fit on Super User should not be allowed on the Apple-specific site, but the fact is that both accept them. For the same reason, I wouldn't like a Windows-specific site.

Comment: @Arjan, by your same logic [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) shouldn't exist either.

Comment: True, @Chris, and I think they shouldn't. (But: that's just me, of course. And at least those sites are limited by technology, not by vendor. But even then I fail to see why there are two such sites.)

Comment: maybe Super User should contain everything between user and applications while Apple and Microsoft etc should get melted into "businesses" or whatever.

Comment: Microsoft users don't need boutique sites for support; we're happy with [su].

Comment: @Arjan Maybe it should be more like the facebook site...

Comment: @Won't If it makes sense to reset your rep, for the good of stack overflow, would you do it?  In other words, are you protecting your turf, or reasoning rationally, for the good of everyone?

Comment: @bordeo Your comment makes absolutely no sense to me.  It's not like I have any rep on SU http://superuser.com/users/939/will Anyhow, the comment was a joke, really.  An opportunity to rip on OS fanbois and their boutique support sites.

Answer (score 31):

Well, the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) community is already strong in the Windows area. A windows site would just split the community (which is counterproductive).

Thing is, Unix/Linux/Ubuntu questions tend to be on the coding side at times, and Super User can't handle that very well. On the other hand, Windows is rather locked down when it comes to coding -- not much to do there. So it fits perfectly on Super User.

Comment: Ha, "split the community" (as opposed to the Ubuntu/Unix/Serverfault split...)

Comment: @steve well, that's got a different reason that doesn't apply here. Chronology: SF came first, then AU, then U&L (also AU is a special tie up or an SE 1.0 import iirc). In this order, subset sites were not a problem. Creating a subset site _now_ is more of an issue.

Comment: I disagree. Having a windows.SE site would be better than using SuperUser.SE IMHO.

Comment: This is a typical BS, old school "smug" stack overflow response.  It's not a matter of splitting the community...it's a matter of having a clear way to obey the militant stack overflow rule thumpers, and avoid the hate.  Also, without a clear place to ask windows questions, you can't accrue windows specific knowledge...and lacking the global "windows" header to the questions means that searches are less effective...so the stack mission of creating a repository of long term answers is impacted negatively.

Comment: Also, the "community will be split" is a non-issue.  When I want a coke, I get up out of my chair, walk over to the kitchen, and get a coke.  I've just done 1,000,000,000 times more work than it takes to twitch my finger and click a button to move from the SuperUser site to the Windows site. Wow.   Really, what you are talking about is "splitting reputation"...my answer is: so what.  Just transition the questions to the windows side.. the rep will build faster now that the searches are more effective. (btw, I've NEVER gotten a windows question on stack through a search)

Comment: Superuser *is* the "clear place to ask windows questions", it's always been very heavily windows, and is known for this. SEO is solved by tags. I do recognize that since this answer was written Stack Exchange has tried to have much tinier sites and succeeded, so I'm more receptive to this, but I still feel it largely unnecessary. As far as community splitting is concerned, that has nothing to do with effort and everything to do with people. SE won't transition questions, and I wasn't talking about rep.

Comment: SuperUser homepage says "for computer enthusiasts and power users". Ok, cool. But, where do Windows admins and professionals ask questions?

Comment: SuperUser is too picky about what are considered valid questions when they relate to windows 10, and especially the guts of networking.  It constantly threatens users if they don't phrase their questions just right.

Answer (score 4):

There is a beta site that might interest you:

- [**Windows Phone**](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/). Windows Phone is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Phone OS.

Comment: i will do as best as i can.

Comment: Bit confused - this proposal is for windows phone, not windows. Therefore its not terribly relevant here is it?

Comment: @JonEgerton There was a windows proposal but it failed, see [the edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/124214/revisions).